# WPF: how to get my TextBox text property using command

Tags: wpf, binding, textbox

So this is what i have try:

```
<TextBox Name="TextBoxLatter">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
               <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=TextBoxKeyDownCommand}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TextBoxLatter, Path=Text}"/>
           </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

And inside my `Execute` method my `parameter` is `null`:

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach should work if you handle the `KeyUp` event instead of `KeyDown`.

But you should bind the `Text` property of `TextBoxLatter` to a `string` source property of the view model. You could then access it directly in the `Execute` method of the command:

```
public void Execute(object _)
{
    string text = this.YourProperty;
    //...
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox Name="TextBoxLatter" Text="{Binding YourProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=TextBoxKeyDownCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```